# How Can I limit this Jquery Transition to a small area around a cursor?

Tags: jquery

So I want to put together this interactive art project where two images are overlaid. Only a portion of the background image is revealed when the cursor goes over it. Essentially I want to do the same as this example: http://css.dzone.com/news/jquery-image-cross-fade-transi but not with the whole image. Is this possible?

Comment: Use png transparency and cut holes on your overlay image.

Answer (score 1):

It would take a little time to develop but in principle would work as follows:

1. In HTML, create a div (poition:relative) containing five imgs (position:absolute; left:0; top:0;).
2. Bottom img - src="...src1", z-index 0.
3. Other four imgs (overlays) - src="...src2", z-index:1.
4. div.onMouseover - start monitoring mousemove.
5. div.onMousemove - read mouse position and set the four overlays' CSS clip properties
   to give a rectangular/square "hole" around the cursor, through which the bottom img shows.
6. div.onMouseout - stop monitoring mousemove and restore clips to show at least one full overlay.

As far as I'm aware, there's no easy way to make anything other than a rectangular/square hole. But maybe someone knows differently.

Comment: Thanks. I'll have to look into it.

Comment: Maybe not exactly what you want but certainly the easiest achievable - http://jsfiddle.net/V7yDJ/. It's actually simpler than in my sketch-plan above in that a single overlay is clipped to give the effect.